# How can I take screen shots of an app that uses the camera on Android

Tags: android, camera

I have finished developing an application that uses a camera preview for the bottom layer of a RelativeLayout. When I take screenshots using DDMS, the Camera preview is just shown as black. How can I include the preview image in the screenshot?

Comment: Did you tried DDMS screen capture which is built-in in eclipse IDE.

Comment: yeah I just tried it and the camera preview is black .

Comment: So the problem is related to specific device , I have got two devices one is of HTC which isn't showing preview and but Galaxy S Captivate is showing. So you can try it with another device. Thanks